# Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Undefined array key

Tags: magento2

I have this error after i try to save data from my admin grid. How to fix this error.

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Undefined array key "card_pin" in /var/www/html/rakuten_magento/app/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Controller/Adminhtml/Card/Save.php on line 36

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Undefined array key "card_pin" in /var/www/html/rakuten_magento/app/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Controller/Adminhtml/Card/Save.php on line 36
<pre>#1 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Save->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#2 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Save\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#3 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#4 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Controller/Adminhtml/Card/Save/Interceptor.php:23]
#5 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Save\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:151]
#7 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#8 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Save\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#9 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:145]
#10 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#11 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#12 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Controller/Adminhtml/Card/Save/Interceptor.php:32]
#13 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Save\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:245]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:212]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:147]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]
</pre>
```

Here is my controller Save file:

```
public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $id = !empty($data['entity_id']) ? $data['entity_id'] : null;
 
        $newData = [
            'card_pin' => $data['card_pin'],
            'status' => $data['status'],
            'content' => $data['content'],
        ];
 
        $post = $this->postFactory->create();
 
        if ($id) {
            $post->load($id);
        }
        try {
            $post->addData($newData);
            $post->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the post.'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
 
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('helloworld/card/index');
    }
```

Comment: what does it mean, could you explain to me ?

Comment: how can i get the value ?

Comment: ok, i can fix it now it all start from my admin form.xml, i did not change the data scope

Comment: Please see the outcome if key value coming or not: $this->getRequest()->getParams();

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your $data contains the array key card_pin

```
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($data);
 exit;
```

paste this code after this line

`$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();`

in your execute function

Comment: So where did you set this from admin form make sure your field name should have same name i.e. card_pin, you can check this by displaying data did your post array contains card_pin or not .

Comment: Can you please share your code from admin form where you have created this field 'card_pin'

Answer (score 0):

[image]ok so i do add like you recommend and i see it already has it. You can check the image below

Answer (score 0):

try to do this like

```
 if (isset($data["card_pin"])) {
     //paste your code here
 }
 else {
      $data['card_pin'] = null;
 }
```

Did you check Line No 36 ?
Is It this one

```
 $newData = [
        **'card_pin' => $data['card_pin']**,
        'status' => $data['status'],
        'content' => $data['content'],
    ];
```